# Play MKV video using videojs on ios

Tags: ios, iphone, video.js

I have integrated videojs in my website and there are mostly Mkv files to play in videojs. Now the concern is that iPhone is not playing Mkv videos and showing messages like "format not supported". If anyone has an idea regarding this issue or any alternative, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 video has to be a format supported by the browser natively, or via media source extensions. MKV is not supported by iOS nor widely supported on desktop browsers - even if some play, others will not.

If you need a single video format, MP4/h.264/aac is the most widely supported format, but consider HLS for adaptive streaming.

Comment: Safari on iOS supports low-complexity AAC audio, MP3 audio, AIF audio, WAVE audio, and baseline profile MPEG-4 video. Safari on the desktop (Mac OS X and Windows) supports all media supported by the installed version of QuickTime, including any installed third-party codecs.

Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html